# TeamCity - NAnt - Failed to start build

Tags: teamcity, nant

I have a very basic installation/configuration in TeamCity and I'm using a NAnt build step with a target that strictly echoes out a message and nothing more.  I've confirmed that NAnt is working properly on my machine but when I attempt to call it in my build I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.systemProblems_jsp
```

At the bottom I see a message that says:

```
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.23 logs.
```

I'm not sure where this actual stacktrace would be, but I'm seeing other errors in some other log files:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file
```

Comment: Is this a TeamCity error message (given that NAnt is .net)?

Comment: No I think this has to do with possibly that I'm trying to check out the entire svn.  It's not letting me put the checkout at the .../src/trunk directory.

Comment: That seems to be quite a bit different to what you have described in the question. Do you have a log you could post?

Comment: This was happening because SVN in linux is case-sensitive so I had to do /Src/trunk and it was timing out.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening because SVN in linux is case-sensitive so I had to do /Src/trunk and it was timing out. Thanks for the help.